# Sphinx Multiple Sources - One Index

Tags: indexing, sphinx

Assuming that I have a database with 20 some tables, all with the same schema, how do I create one index for all tables?
If I have ONE index per table, the search works just fine.
I successfully created ONE index for the 20 tables, but every search returns the first record of the first table.

Index conf:

```
index all_table_index
{
    type            = plain
    source          = TABLE1
    source          = TABLE2
    source          = TABLE3 
    source          = TABLE4
    source          = TABLE5
    ...
    path            = /data/sphinx/all_table_index
    #docinfo        = extern
    charset_type    = utf-8
}
```

Additionally: The unique integer field has duplicates (Primary ID Auto increment - same for each table!). Does that affect any search for any other fields?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

*> The unique integer field has duplicates (Primary ID Auto increment - same for each table!).*

That is your problem.

The document-id MUST be unique. Its how sphinx tracks documents, so if you have multiple documents with the same id, they will override each other, and you then have no way to distingish the seperate underlying documents.

... So you need to arrange for the IDS to be unique.

There are many ways to do it, eg

```
sourse TABLE1 {
sql_query = SELECT id*20 as id, ... from table1

sourse TABLE2 {
sql_query = SELECT (id*20)+1 as id, ... from table2

sourse TABLE3 {
sql_query = SELECT (id*20)+2 as id, ... from table3
```

etc...

Comment: I decided to create one index per table. The query goes to all indexes, I do not have to retouch the primary keys on any tables, and the query time does not seem to be affected. Any comments? Best Practice?

Comment: You will have the same problem. If you have documents with the same ids in differnt indexes, you wont be able to get the individual documents. (unless you query each index seperately)

Answer (score 1):

Usually use this

```
source TABLE1 {
sql_query = SELECT CONCAT(id,01) as id, 'table1' AS source, '01' AS source_code,   ... from table1
sql_attr_string = source
sql_attr_str2ordinal = source_code
```

- **01** and not 1, 001 if  more than 100 sources (but never happen for me)
- **'table1' AS source** just to easy know the source"
- **'01' AS source_code** just to easy  filter, or groupby